# Is there any difference in performance between assigning a long string to a variable and subsequently appending smaller strings to a variable?

Tags: php, performance, variable-assignment

As the title says, is there a difference in performance between:

```
$var = "Very             long              string               to                       add";
```

and

```
$var = "Appending";
$var.= "subsequentially";
$var.= "short";
$var.= "strings";
```

I like to use the second method becouse i can keep the code more clean, but I'm worried multiple assignments could affect performance, is it something worth worrying about?

Is there a way to test it maybe?

Comment: I don't think so it will create any impact and if it create it will be an unnoticeable but for a readability breaking string is good.

Comment: The "performance" is such an irrelevant topic when dealing with strings of such tiny length it's not even worth wasting your time. If you're deciding between two different approaches, your argument should be which one is readable, not which one shaves off a nanosecond.

Comment: well, i'm dealing with strings much longer than those, but i get the point

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to measure it ... [see this function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) ... but hard to say how much precise this would be.

Test example is below.

```
<?php

$s1 = microtime(true);
$var1 = "Very             long              string               to                          add";
$e1 = microtime(true);

$s2 = microtime(true);
$var2 = "Appending";
$var2.= "subsequentially";
$var2.= "short";
$var2.= "strings";
$e2 = microtime(true);

echo 'Big string: ' . number_format($e1 - $s1, 9, '.', '') . 's';
echo PHP_EOL;
echo 'Appended: ' . number_format($e2 - $s2, 9, '.', '') . 's';
```

Tests looked mostly like this:

```
Big string: 0.000001907s
Appended: 0.000002146s

Big string: 0.000000954s
Appended: 0.000003099s

Big string: 0.000000954s
Appended: 0.000002146s
```

Both solutions take up max 1 or 2 micro-seconds, so, ... **yes, the appending technique is a little more performance-costly, but not so significantly that you should care** :) ...

... unless you count every micro-second, then i would recommend you a language other than PHP.

Comment: Thanks, very useful!